# Scrolling by swipe over the block

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, css, scroll

I have a little problem with my website on the phone.

http://gyazo.com/3e2f0297e28b2f68f251feaf53faddb6.

I can scroll when I swiping on the white background, but I can't over the thumbnails. I don't have any events binded on this section.

What can be a problem?

Here are the styles that I've got using Chrome remote debugging from my phone:

```
http://gyazo.com/309ceb1a491e809d2faac073c263c178
http://gyazo.com/c9a88cf1dc4689ee47bb899f189c4a55
http://gyazo.com/428310e02f3af9e06747993af2d67617
```

previewThumb is the class of thumbnails in project-preview (block where are all thumbnails).

Thanks for any help!

Comment: not getting the question